# Can't boot after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, white-screen

Alright, I'll go straight to the point. I installed Ubuntu 2204 alongside with Win 11 in a HP 15s laptop then installed Cutefish desktop. Unfortunately, Cutefish is faulty and I can't get rid of it. I rebooted and when I was booting the laptop up, it shows nothing rather than a black screen. I can't get to either GRUB or BIOS. How to fix this? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You can ALWAYS access the firmware (UEFI) settings. And yes, it's UEFI, not BIOS, since at least 2012. Access to UEFI or BIOS is ALWAYS independent of the installed OS, if any.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you have in front of you a complete black screen and no way to access even the BIOS?

Are you sure you are pressing the right key to access your laptop BIOS?

If yes, and all the above is correct, you can try to put a USB in with some bootable system and see if you can boot from the USB stick pressing the correct key for the boot menu when starting it up.

If even that fails, and you still have no access to you machine, software wise let's say, you can try to 'brute force' it.

Open up the machine, remove the HDD/SSD, plug it in another computer in any way you like (Internal SATA or External USB converter, generally speaking) and put it a fresh install of whatever OS you would like to run, or restore a previously created environment if you have done so.

Maybe someone else more knowledge than me may have a fancier solution, but this I can almost guarantee you it will work, I have done it a couple of times in some similar 'extreme' situation were a machine OS complete broke.

Just a note, if your machine it is still under warranty, you may void it if you open it.

Comment: Please understand the OP is mistaken. Please DON'T suggest mucking with hardware to a person that don't even understand the basics.

Comment: Well I can't open my laptop, and I've tried using a bootable USB, going to BIOS by using the ESC key but it's no use

Comment: @ThiênMinhTrần (1) It's UEFI, not BIOS, since a decade ago. (2) Please read your user's manual to understand how (and which key) enables access to the firmware (UEFI) settings. This, again, is completely independent of the installed OS, dual-boot, or no OS at all. This happens (and MUST happen) before any OS starts loading so, immediately after powering on and typically you have to spam the assigned key. Yes, for HP this typically can be achieved with ESC > F10 or F10 directly.

Comment: F9 opens the one-time boot menu (AKA boot override). And, again, it must be press IMMEDIATELY after powering on as there's only a very small time window for it.

Comment: Well, I think you people got carried away a bit with my 'awful' suggestion.
I spent the first half of the answer saying that's strange and he should be able to access BIOS.
THAN I just let him know of a 'final stand' solution which ALWAYS works, with all the disclosure needed AND concluding saying AGAIN that probably there is another solution ayway (software wise).
Honestly, when I ask for help, I appreciate everything that it is been suggested to me, as long as it works. It will be my judgment then to choose what I would like to do.
But hey, everyone it is different...